# Not able to update bit in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with following sql:

```
CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  `enabled` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `end_date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `image_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `start_date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

When i run the following command with a user that has permissions to insert, i get the following result:

```
mysql> insert into event (description, enabled, end_date_time, image_url, start_date_time, title) values ('asdf', 1, NOW(), 'asdf', NOW(), 'asf');
```

Why am i not able to update the 'enabled' flag?

```
mysql> select * from event;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+-------+
| id | created_date        | modified_date       | description | enabled | end_date_time       | image_url | start_date_time     | title |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+-------+
|  1 | 2017-05-29 17:10:39 | 2017-05-29 17:10:39 | DESCRIPTION |        | 2017-05-29 17:10:39 | URL       | 2017-05-29 17:10:39 | TITLE |
|  2 | NULL                | NULL                | asdf        |        | 2017-05-29 22:00:32 | asdf      | 2017-05-29 22:00:32 | asf   |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

---

**Note**

```
mysql> select if((select enabled from event where id = 2), 'true', 'false');
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| if((select enabled from event where id = 2), 'true', 'false') |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| true                                                          |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update event set enabled = 0;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

mysql> select if((select enabled from event where id = 2), 'true', 'false');
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| if((select enabled from event where id = 2), 'true', 'false') |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| false                                                         |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Are you using PHPmyadmin? Some versions of PHPmyadmin has issue displaying the value of bit fields even though the value is still there. Can you confirm the field is empty? Try doing a `SELECT`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting it fine.  It's just that when it's displayed, it's showing up as \x01, which is an unprintable character.

(What happens if you run `SELECT * FROM events WHERE enabled=1`?)

Things might be more intuitive if you use tinyint(1) instead of bit(1) for this column.

Comment: I am using terminal to run the mysql commands.  You are right.  I have added a note in my original post to show the value of 'enabled' as true or false.  I was using hibernate and it created the table for me and it chose bit instead of tinyint(1).